# Sliding down element which has a higher z-index value doesn't push down the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm populating a box created with HTML which has a sliding down panel at the bottom of the card.It slides down when clicked on "More" button. Sliding down part has a higher z-index value than the other elements in the page.

When the panel of the last box slides down it goes beyond the footer without pushing the footer down.

[image: Panel goes beyond the footer]

css of the footer

```css
.footer {
  font-size:14px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #909090;

  line-height: 25px;
  position: relative; /* sticky footer */
  margin-top: -26px; /* sticky footer */
  height: 26px; /* sticky footer */
  top:50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both; /* sticky footer */
}
```

css for the sliding down panel

```css
.detailPanelClass{
  color:#4D4D4D;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: -1px;
  right:-1px;
  border-radius:0;
  display:none;
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1em;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  border-top:0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);

}
```

I want to push the footer down when the panel slides down.I searched a lot in Google and stackoverflowe. But i couldn't find an answer. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Elements with `position:absolute` are out of the flow and cannot affect other elements around them. You would have to remove that property at a minimum.

Comment: @Paulie_D, The detail panel slides down without moving any other cards in the page. In order to do so i use `position:absolute;`  .I want only the footer to be pushed down when the panel expands. Thanks for tip.

Comment: Not sure I see a way out if this. You want the opening to affect some other elements (the footer) but not others (other cards). About the only thing I can think of is to somehow calculate the height of the opened panel and move the footer that much (if it can, in fact be moved). We're gonna need a proper demo to work on that possibility.

Comment: I had an idea that i might have to use the approach you have mentioned here. I posted this to check if there is a much more efficient and easy answer in css.I guess i may have to implement a script to overcome the issue.